# Improvements to "review" for a tablet device

Tags: feature-request, usability, review

I review Stack Overflow questions on my tablet. For the most part, the new interface works great, but I have a few suggestions which I think may improve usability when working with a tablet:

1. The different options under "close" have links in them. It's easy to click these instead of the text around it which navigates away from the review page. Maybe these links could be moved out of the radio button text and e.g. to a list under the options.
2. On a device like a tablet, it's easy to click the wrong button (I mean the "close", "do not close" etc. buttons). It would be great if the page after e.g. clicking the "do not close" button (which doesn't ask for confirmation) would show an "undo" option. Currently there is no way (I can easily find) to undo a review action.

Comment: I have removed the suggestion to open links in new tabs. It seems there is no issue with navigating back to the review page since it keeps track of where you were quite well.

Comment: Yes. I review questions a lot on it.

Comment: I totally agree - I have made a number of review errors by accidentally clicking the wrong button on my mobile phone, and then people have the nerve to down-vote you for the mistake. There really needs to be an option to Undo/Change a review